# Executing Java program through command window

Tags: java

I have one query that Since I am using eclipse mostly to execute the java class but I want to know if I am not using eclipse and I want to execute the java program then I have to manually set the path and classpath also , I have my jdk inside java folder in C: drive and my program is inside folder named AA namded as Temp.java , Please advise how to set path and classpath for this in order to execute the java program from command window itself..!

Comment: Did you try to `Google`-it out? Something like this: ["Hello World!" for Microsoft Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) and ["Common Problems (and Their Solutions)"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)

Comment: @Cdeez, please refrain from `adding` random `code` formatting to blocks.  It actively makes the text harder to read.

Comment: @Charles Ok. Will follow it from the next time I edit a post

Comment: Mr. Google will surely help you (that too in image format)

Comment: I asked Mr. Google and he replied me with [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Programing-with-Java-using-Command-Prompt/?ALLSTEPS) & [this](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can set environment path of install jdk bin path then you can compile and run java program from any location.

```
My compute->right click->system properties->advanced tab->select system variable path-> select edit->then add your jdk bin path. save the setting.
```

**Setting Path on Windows**

```
Windows 7
Select Computer from the Start menu
Choose System Properties from the context menu
Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
```

[Refrence](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: @Mohammaod Can you please show in the updated example that will make understanding more clear..!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path to the current working directory by using:

```
path=%path%;c:\Java\jdk[followedbyversion]\bin
```

This sets the path temporarily, and on a fresh boot of your system, you will have to set the path again.

If working on Windows, you can permanently set the path using an environment variable. Right click on your My Computer -> Properties -> Advance System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Then add an user environment variable,name it path and set the path to jdk's bin.

Comment: if you literally want to add the current working directory to path temporarily couldn't you just do `path=%path%;.`?

Comment: We need to set the path to the directory where we can find the `javac` and `java` binaries, hence the path to the `bin`.